# Как поменять url проекта на github pages

Tags: javascript, reactjs, github, react-router-dom

У меня есть проблема.
Мой проект находится по данной ссылке https://pqvel.github.io/fakeStore/, но мне нужно чтобы url был без слеша на конце: https://pqvel.github.io/fakeStore.

При первом заходе на страницу рендерится только header, при переходе по ссылке какой-нибудь и обратно уже отображается компонент MainPage и url становится таким https://pqvel.github.io/fakeStore.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Или может есть какой нибудь способ, при помощи которого отображался бы компонент MainPage по ссылкe https://pqvel.github.io/fakeStore/ не изменяя пути у Link, которые ведут на MainPage?